# Save Current Date into 3 Ints - C++

Tags: c++, date

I would like to save the current day, month, and year into three ints.  I have no idea how to do this.

```
int day;
int month;
int year;
```

Comment: Where is my "no (research) effort" close reason when I need it...

Comment: @Jonathan: Read the description of that close reason again. It might be the only applicable reason we have, but it's not the *correct* reason.

Comment: This shouldn't be closed, only downvoted.

Comment: @Xeo I disagree. This question is clearly incomplete.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
#include <ctime>

int main() {
    time_t t = time(0);  // current time: http://cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/ctime/time/
    struct tm * now = localtime(&t);  // http://cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/ctime/localtime/

    // struct tm: http://cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/ctime/tm/
    int day = now->tm_mday;
    int month = now->tm_mon + 1;
    int year = now->tm_year + 1900;
}
```

#### Links from above

- `time(0)`: current time:
  http://cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/ctime/time/
- `localtime`:
  http://cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/ctime/localtime/
- `struct tm`:
  http://cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/ctime/tm/

Comment: Thanks so much! Didn't have a clue how to use ctime or any of these things. Very very very novice with C++

Answer (score 0):

Ok as you don't know anything about it you can find it here

http://www.cs.utah.edu/dept/old/texinfo/glibc-manual-0.02/library_19.html

everything in detail.

Answer (score 0):

David's answer above should do the trick, but here's another version (dependent upon Windows platform)

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>



int main()
{
char key;
int day;
int month;
int year;

    SYSTEMTIME st;
    GetSystemTime(&st);


printf("%02d-%02d-%04d %02d:%02d:%02d.%03d\n", st.wMonth, st.wDay, st.wYear, st.wHour, st.wMinute, st.wSecond, st.wMilliseconds);


day = st.wDay;
month = st.wMonth;
year = st.wYear;


std::cin >> key;

return 0;
}
```

Hope this helps!

-CCJ

Reference: http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/48115/