# Use time as int for calculation in function?

Tags: c++, function, header-files

Hi guys I'm working on a project where I need to find the age of a patient using a function in a header file. I'm trying to use division and remainder to separate the current date into Month, Day, and Year. The problem is I can't seem to find a way to use the current date as an integer. Here's the portion of my code I'm having trouble with.

```
int PatientDemographicInformation::getPatientAge( )
{
    int patientBirthMonth = patientDateOfBirth / 1000000;
    int patientBirthDay = (patientDateOfBirth % 1000000) / 10000;
    int patientBirthYear = patientDateOfBirth % 10000;

    // What can I use on the line below to get the current date/time as an int?
    int currentTime = /*What can I use here?*/
    int currentMonth = currentTime / 1000000;
    int currentDay = (currentTime % 1000000) / 10000;
    int currentYear = currentTime % 10000;

    if (currentMonth >= patientBirthMonth)
    {
        if (patientBirthDay < currentDay)
        {
            int patientAge = (currentYear - patientBirthYear) - 1;
        }
        else
        {
        int patientAge = currentYear - patientBirthYear;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        int patientAge = currentYear - patientBirthYear;
    }
    return patientBirthMonth;
}
```

Again, this is a function in my header file, the file is pretty long but I can give more code if needed. Please help me in anyway you can.

Thanks

Comment: Define "not working."  Does it refuse to compile?  If so, give error messages.  Does it compile but give incorrect answers?  If so, mention what it gives, and also what it *should* give.

Comment: It won't compile, it says it can't use '/' or '%' operators for each of those three lines. Am I using the time correctly?

Comment: It's defined in the constructor as an int.

Comment: Found answer here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8264400/save-current-date-into-3-ints-c

Anyway, thank you for your help guys.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that your mixing two completely different things.

patientDateOfBirth probably comes from a database where the string "12/21/1994" is stored as the number 12211994.  So the code at the top unpacks that.

time is something else completely.  Give that it won't let you do a '/' operator on them, the value in time[9] might be a structure, an object, or even a string.  You are going to have to find more out about what time[] is, and what its values are.

Comment: I want to use time[9] for the current time, I took it from an example hoping it would work but as you said I think it's from a table made in their code that isn't in mine. So how would I go about replacing 'time[9]' with the current time? Is there anyway to retrieve and store the time as, 11192013, for example?